# QML and Opengl : QQuickFramebufferObject::renderer is never deleted once the view (QQuickFramebufferObject instance) id deleted

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

My opengl application is based on classic Qml architecture :

- a QQuickFramebufferObject instance (my view)
- a QQuickFramebufferObject::renderer ( my renderer).

**Remark : The OpenglContext is shared (Qt::ApplicationAttribute::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)**

This renderer is composed by several QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core instances.

One of them is working with a texture.

The texture is initiated inside the Renderer::render() method and also destroyed inside it.

When I tried to close my application, the view is deleted but not my renderer then the application does not close.

When I reduce my code as much as possible, It seems the issue happens because of :

> tex=new QOpenGLTexture(image);  ...

when I move to another QOPenGlTExture ctor :

> tex=new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D); // line 1
> tex->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear); // line 2
> ....

Issue happens when line 2 is enabled .

If I change to raw opengl functions (Non DSA) like :

> glGenTextures(1, &id);   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
> glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
>
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
> 0,
> GL_RGBA,
> img.width(),
> img.height(),
> 0,
> GL_RGBA,
> GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
> img.bits());    ...

It works well .

**Remark :** the display is always correct : texture is correctly used but the issue is only related to a fail of the Renderer destruction .

Thank you All

Answer (score 0):

My Fault ...
Actually issue only happens on Intel HD 630.
Opengl Context was forced to be 3.3 (using QOpenGlSurfaceFormat::setVersion(int major, int minor).

Removing this method resolves the issue.